# Aligning images on WPF bing maps

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, bing-maps

Just ran into issue that aligning is not working for WPF Bing Maps if it's specified while creating image:

```
var element = new Image()
        {
            Source = ResourceManager.VesselIcon,
            Opacity = 0.9,
            Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.None,

            VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center, // Is not working
            HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center
        };
```

Fortunatley WPF Bing Maps API do provide "PositionOrigin" structure. So one can specify alignment while adding shape to map itself:

```
Location location = Helper.SomeLocation();
this.mapLayer.AddChild(element, location, PositionOrigin.Center);
```

Hope it will help somebody

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and then mark that answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunatley WPF Bing Maps API do provide "PositionOrigin" structure. So one can specify alignment while adding shape to map itself:

```
Location location = Helper.SomeLocation();
this.mapLayer.AddChild(element, location, PositionOrigin.Center);
```